# laravel 4.2 logs on command prompt and not in laravel.log

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.2, whenever i use Log::info() or Log::Error(). The expected logs doesn't store in laravel.log   instead it outputs on command prompt from where it is served. can any one suggest me how i can log those things in my laravel.log file.

Comment: Normally, Laravel 4.2 logs to `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`. Difficult to resolve your problem without more infos. Didi you change some settings before? Can you post an example on how you use `Log::info()`

Comment: Hi i might have changed some setting. but i don't remember what i did exactly. Log::info('hello') . i have given this in my controller.

Comment: Ohoh so I'd say install a fresh copy of laravel somewhere and compare configs. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's for laravel only. You should create a new folder with a class of Logs.

For example:

in Folder Logs:

```
class example_logs{

 public static function viewLogs($datas){

   echo 'Your Error' . $datas;
 }

}
```

in your Controller:

```
Logs::viewlogs($datas);
```